# Using HttpClient.ReadAsStringAsync() to return result string via function

Tags: vb.net, httpclient

I am calling a web API that returns a JSON string.  This is the first time I am using HttpClient and I can't figure out how to get a function to return a string.

```
Public Async Function CallWebAPI(sIPAddress As String, sCommand As String) As Task(Of String)

    Try
        Using client As HttpClient = New HttpClient()
            Using response As HttpResponseMessage = Await client.GetAsync("http://" + sIPAddress + "/" + sCommand)
                Using content As HttpContent = response.Content
                    Dim result As String = content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result
                    If result IsNot Nothing Then
                        Return result
                    End If
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using
        Return True

    Catch ex As Exception
        Debug.WriteLine("ERROR: " + ex.Message)
        Return "ERROR"

    End Try

End Function
```

I am calling the function using:

```
Dim sConfig As String = CallWebAPI("192.168.0.100", "getLevel")
```

I can't even compile this.  I am getting an error when I call the `CallWebAPI` function:

> Value of 'Task(Of String)' cannot be converted to 'String'

Any ideas?  What am I missing here?

Comment: `Dim sConfig As String = Await CallWebAPI("192.168.0.100", "getLevel")` => `Public Async Function CallWebAPI(...) Return Await content.ReadAsStringAsync() '[...] End Function` -- HttpClient should be declared as a static (`Shared`) Field (initialized once, used many times, until not needed anymore, then disposed)

Answer (score 0):

Asynchronous functions actually return Task objects. For example take this function:-

```
    Public Async Function GetStringAsync() As Task(Of String)
        Dim result As String = "Async func"

        Return result
    End Function
```

The above is an asynchronous function that returns a String. But what it actually returns is a Task object. It would be equivalent to writing this:-

```
    Public Function GetStringAsync2() As Task(Of String)
        Dim result As String = "Non async func"

        'Wraps it in a Task object
        Return Task.FromResult(result)
    End Function
```

The 'Async' modifier is not present in this one so we must wrap it in a Task(Of T) ourselves but both versions return a Task(Of T). The proper way to extract these values is by using Await. Example:-

```
        Debug.WriteLine(Await GetStringAsync())

        Debug.WriteLine(Await GetStringAsync2())
```

So the correction you need to make is to change this:-

```
Dim sConfig As String = CallWebAPI("192.168.0.100", "getLevel")
```

To this:-

```
Dim sConfig As String = Await CallWebAPI("192.168.0.100", "getLevel")
```

Comment: If you return this: `Return Task.FromResult("ERROR")`, the method's return Type should be `Task(Of Task(Of String))`

Comment: My bad. I should write code when I'm sleepy lol. Edited and added the Await operator.

Comment: You can simply return the string, it's wrapped in a Task already. `return await SomeThing()` does return the Type that `SomeThing()` returns, it's unwrapped by `await`. Different thing in case `SomeThing()` is not async... Anyway, the important part for the OP is that these async calls need to be awaited, that should be clear enough

Comment: You're right I re-checked it this time. I confused it with a normal function that returns a Task(Of T) which would require Task.FromResult to work correctly. If the function is defined with "async", it would do that automatically. Thank you.